Get Android Gallery Folder
I want to show photos by album like on Instagram. How can I get the gallery album folder?
How can I get photos from a path other than the DCIM path?

There is no Gallery folder. And you get photos from a path in rhe same way as from DCIM. Show your DCIM code.

you can achieve this with the MediaStore API
